Why is this not finding words containing the letters if one of them starts with the letter?
I have the following Expression: /\w+(?=\w*a)(?=\w*i)\w+/gi
This is what I'm using to find words in my list that have an a and an i in them.
Out of the following words: gain affix pikes rabid simple claim again peanut orange it does not find affix. Is there something special I have to do if the word starts with one of the letters? Currently in regex101.com gain, rabid, claim and again are highlighted as being found but affix is not.

\w+ matches one or more word characters. So after at least one \w your current pattern looks ahead for the a but it's the first letter in affix. So you need to do something like \b(?=\w*i)\w*a\w* or without lookahead \b\w*?(?:a\w*i|i\w*a)\w*.

Thanks bobble, I ended up with \b(?=\w*a)(?=\w*i)\w*\b which seems to have done the trick.

Glad it helped, you can spare one of the lookaheads and normally match instead which is a bit more efficient: \b(?=\w*a)\w*i\w*

Or perhaps \b(?=[^\Wa]*a)[^\Wi]*i\w* https://regex101.com/r/KdtXSD/1

@bobblebubble Your explanation for why OPs regex doesn't work looks good enough for an answer. That you also provide a working solution is a great bonus.

@Thefourthbird this indeed looks to be turbo efficient (subtracting the two letters from \w to match the characters in between).

@bobblebubble It's just for fun, it does make it less readable.

The reason that your regex does not match affix is that you put the lookahead after \w+ which matches one or more word characters. But a is the first letter in this word. It would match strings with another a after the first letter like again. Further it's a good practice to put the lookahead at some fixed point if possible.
You could use a word boundary \b and put the lookahead there, so it will look ahead before any word characters and spot the a. A lookahead is a zero length assertion (condition). Also for your task it's sufficient to use just one lookahead and normally match the other character which is a bit more efficient, so you could use:
\b(?=\w*?a)\w*i\w*

See this demo at regex101 or if lookarounds are not available: \b\w*?(?:a\w*i|i\w*a)\w*
